# How to execute Jquery code in vue.js. I wan to run JQuery in vue.js

Tags: html, jquery, vue.js

Here I am trying to run jQuery code in vue.js. Without vue.js my jQuery code is running fine but when I am adding vue.js cdn The is not working. Here I am trying while user enters a value in form input fields if suddenly session logouts or user navigate to a different page the form field value should not clear. That I have written in jQuery but while i am using that code in vue.js method I am unable to get the output. So how to run jQuery code in vue.js please help me.

```
<div class="">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" id="xgh" name="firstname" class="auto-save">
    <br><br>


    Description:<br>
    <textarea name="name" id="uzt" rows="8" cols="80" class="auto-save"></textarea>
    <br><br>


    Preferred car manufacturer :<br>
    <select id="dfj" class="auto-save">
      <option value="none" selected>--</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <br><br> 

    Gender :<br>
    <input id="gho" class="auto-save" type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
    <input id="jdw" class="auto-save" type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Male
    <br><br>

  </div>
```

**vue.js**

```
new Vue({
 el: '#q-vikreya',
    data() {
            return {
            step:1,
            firstname:'',
            Description:'',
            Manufacture:'',
            gender:'',
    methods: {
      submitForm: function(){
            axios({
                method : "POST",
                url: "{% url 'PostAd' %}", //django path name
                headers: {'X-CSRFTOKEN': '{{ csrf_token }}', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                data : {"category":this.category, "title":this.title,
                "address":this.address,
                "city": this.city,
                "state": this.state,
                "zip": this.zip,
                "price": this.price,
                "description": this.description,
                "radio_price": this.radio_price,
                "Job_title": this.model,
                },//data
              }).then(response => {
              console.log("response");
              console.log(response.data);
                  this.success_msg = response.data['msg'];
                 window.location.replace('{% url "classifieds" %}')  // Replace home by the name of your home view

              }).catch(err => {
                     this.err_msg = err.response.data['err'];
              console.log("response1");
              console.log(err.response.data);

              });

          },

  },

})
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>
$('.auto-save').savy('load',function(){
  console.log("All data from savy are loaded");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what error you are getting and whats not working

Comment: I am not getting any error but while i am using this vue.js cdn  "<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>". At that time my JQuery code is not working and if I am removing this cdn Then its working

Comment: This JQuery code is not working in in vue.js  $('.auto-save').savy('load',function(){
  console.log("All data from savy are loaded");
});

Comment: Try to change the order of both jquery and vue libraries

Comment: how can we put that jQuery script in vue.js method

Comment: You can put it as it is inside mounted or any method it shouldnt be a problem